# GoogleMap with KML zooming and Polygon highlighting

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

This is the code for generating map with a kml file

```
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.711516,-117.395075);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdiv"), myOptions);

var geoLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
                          'http://some.kml.url/kmllayer.kml', 
                           {suppressInfoWindows: true,map: map});

geoLayer.setMap(map);
```

My problem is its always getting at max distance, zoom settings not working even if i try to  map.setCenter() call, its still same.

Another question is when i draw polygons on map, is there any way to highlight inside color of it when someone mouse overs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd question.  Draw an initial polygon with a fill opacity of 0 but stroke opacity of 1.  Have two event listeners attached to the polygon, for mouseover and mouseout.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseover', function() {
    polygon.setOptions({fillOpacity:0.5});
}

google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseout', function() {
    polygon.setOptions({fillOpacity:0.0});
}
```